# java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY007 final method overridden; class=com/google/common/collect/NullsLastOrdering

Tags: migration, websphere, guava

I am in the process of migrating an application from WAS 7 to WAS 8.5. I get the following error during application start up. The error is regarding guava library and the project is using guava-1.5.jar. I am not sure if its an issue with the particular version I am using. I would be glad if someone could throw some light on this issue.

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY007 final method overridden; class=com/google/common/collect/NullsLastOrdering, method=reverse()Lcom/google/common/collect/Ordering;, pc=0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:262)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:853)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:763)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:586)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:627)
at com.ibm.ws.webbeans.services.ScannerServiceImpl.convertClassNamesToClass(ScannerServiceImpl.java:490)
at com.ibm.ws.webbeans.services.ScannerServiceImpl.ecsScan(ScannerServiceImpl.java:422)
at com.ibm.ws.webbeans.services.ScannerServiceImpl.populateBeans(ScannerServiceImpl.java:231)
at com.ibm.ws.webbeans.services.ScannerServiceImpl.populateBeans(ScannerServiceImpl.java:241)
at com.ibm.ws.webbeans.services.JCDIComponentImpl.populateOneDeployedObject(JCDIComponentImpl.java:331)
at com.ibm.ws.webbeans.services.JCDIComponentImpl.isJCDIEnabled(JCDIComponentImpl.java:835)
at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs.metadata.JAXRSServerMetaDataBuilder.buildJAXRSMetaData(JAXRSServerMetaDataBuilder.java:72)
at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs.component.JAXRSComponentImpl.stateChanged(JAXRSComponentImpl.java:269)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stateChanged(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1118)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectEvent(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1353)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.setState(DeployedModuleImpl.java:248)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:636)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
... 62 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guava's `Ordering#reverse` method has never been final in any Guava release. It's only been final in a very, very old version of Google Collections: https://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/diff?r=98&old=92&path=/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.java

So you should look for `google-collect*.jar` in your classpath and get rid of it. It really has no purpose for existence any more.

Comment: I had actually removed the google-collect.jar dependency but some how the project still had a reference to it. But yeah, i was able to resolve this issue.Thanks!